# When i search or asce or dess table null in my DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

When I pass value into my function the Data table display correctly, but when I perform search The table is Null.

```
function Domain(did2) {

    did1 = did2; //localStorage.getItem("did2");
    var url = 'myurl?id=' + did1;
    $.ajax(url, { async: false }).then(function success(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var tab = $("#TableDomain > tbody");
        tab.empty();  
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            var row = $("<tr><td>" + value.Id + "</td><td>" + value.Name + "</td></tr>");
            $("#TableDomain").append(row);
        });
    });
}
<script>
$(function(){
      $("#TableDomain").dataTable();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have errors in console ?

Comment: No, When i load data in Ready function then its ok it will be searchable

Comment: But when it put my function in onclick function Then first time Load data but when i search text then it will nul

Comment: How looks your `url` ?

Comment: "It looks like json"

Comment: My DataTable work in Ready function but not work in onclick events when i select dropdownlist Then it load data in Table but when i search Text then null

Comment: Please include `console.log(data)` and tell me what you've received.

Comment: Nothing occurs becoze When i search in DataTable  from datatable.js so not console work

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this:

```
did1 = did2; //localStorage.getItem("did2");
var url = 'myurl?id=' + did1;
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    async: false,
    success:function success(data) {
         data = JSON.parse(data);
         var tab = $("#TableDomain > tbody");
         tab.empty();  
         $.each(data, function (index, value) {
             var row = $("<tr><td>" + value.Id + "</td><td>" + value.Name + "</td></tr>");
             $("#TableDomain").append(row);
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not it is not Work

Comment: It is hitting your method on server side ?

Comment: I think Yes becoxze hen i change did2 Then Change my Table Data